# Dynamic Value Based on Select in windowManager

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have 2 controls in my tinyMCE popup box: 1 Select, 1 Textbox. What I want to do is populate the textbox based on the selected value. I can get the selected value which is great but what I can't seem to do is set that value to the text box. Any ideas on how to make this work? Here's what I have so far:

```
( function( $ ) {

    tinymce.PluginManager.add( 'my_custom_button', function( editor, url ) {
        editor.addButton( 'my_custom_button', {
            text: 'My Custom Button',
            icon: false,
            onclick: function() {
                editor.windowManager.open( {
                    title: 'My Custom button Settings',
                    body: [
                        {
                            type   : 'listbox',
                            name   : 'customselect',
                            label  : 'Custom Select',
                            values : [
                                { text: 'FOO', value: 'foo' },
                                { text: 'BAR', value: 'bar' }
                            ],
                            onselect : function( listObj ) {

                                // The control object value
                                console.log( listObj.control.settings.value );
                             }
                        },
                        {
                            type   : 'textbox',
                            name   : 'customtext',
                            label  : 'Foo or Bar?',
                            value  : ''
                        }
                    ]
                } );
            },
        } );
    } );

} )();
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to find a solution where I accessed only the input in the window but what I ended up doing was settings IDs for both fields and then just setting the values in JS:

```
( function( $ ) {

    tinymce.PluginManager.add( 'my_custom_button', function( editor, url ) {
        editor.addButton( 'my_custom_button', {
            text: 'My Custom Button',
            icon: false,
            onclick: function() {
                var tinyMCEWindow = editor.windowManager.open( {
                    title: 'My Custom button Settings',
                    body: [
                        {
                            type   : 'listbox',
                            name   : 'customselect',
                            label  : 'Custom Select',
                            id     : 'customfoobarselect',
                            values : [
                                { text: 'FOO', value: 'foo' },
                                { text: 'BAR', value: 'bar' }
                            ],
                            onselect : function( listObj ) {
                                document.getElementById( 'customfoobartext' ).value = listObj.control.settings.value;
                             }
                        },
                        {
                            type   : 'textbox',
                            name   : 'customtext',
                            label  : 'Foo or Bar?',
                            id     : 'customfoobartext',
                            value  : ''
                        }
                    ]
                } );
            },
        } );
    } );

} )();
```